# How to replace project references with binaries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have several solutions that reuse the projects in the [DO NOT EDIT] folder. **How can I remove these projects from my solution?**

[image]

I do need the most recent version of this projects always. We obviously do not check-in the binaries. Should we start to do that?

**Without having to configure nuget packages, how do we reference other projects without having to explicitly load them in the same solution?**

Answer (score 2):

You have several options referencing assemblies that aren't in the solution:

1. Supply them as NuGet package.
2. Have them in VCS (tfs, git), e.g. in 'lib' folder and referencing by the relative path.
3. Put them in some server share and referencing them via UNC path, e.g.
   \\SOMESERVER\Assemblies\MyAssembly.dll.

From my experience 1st method works much better than 2nd, and 2nd is better than the 3rd.

However if for some reason you don't want these assemblies in VCS and don't want to configure NuGet packages, then 3rd option should work for you.